# Python pandas `replace` is not acting consistent

Tags: python, pandas, python-re

I have a substantial database where I'm removing leading text of various lengths.  Here's a minimal working example:

```
data = {'Title' : ['Bertram, C. et al., 2015a: Carbon', 
                   'Bertram, C. et al., 2015b: Complementing', 
                   'Bertram, C. et al., 2018: Targeted']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Title'])
```

which gives

```
                                      Title
0         Bertram, C. et al., 2015a: Carbon
1  Bertram, C. et al., 2015b: Complementing
2        Bertram, C. et al., 2018: Targeted
```

**First attempt**

I apply `re` within pandas `replace` method:

```
df['Title'].replace(r'(\A[\D\s.,]*\d\d\d\d[ab:] )', '', regex=True, inplace=True)
```

But that doesn't address all cases:

```
                                      Title
0         Bertram, C. et al., 2015a: Carbon
1  Bertram, C. et al., 2015b: Complementing
2                                  Targeted
```

**Second Attempt**

I use the `regex` command within `replace`:

```
df['Title'].replace(regex=[r'(\A[\D\s.,]*\d\d\d\d:)', 
                           r'(\A[\D\s.,]*\d\d\d\da:)'
                           r'(\A[\D\s.,]*\d\d\d\db:)'], value='', inplace=True)
```

But that gives the same results.

```
                                      Title
0         Bertram, C. et al., 2015a: Carbon
1  Bertram, C. et al., 2015b: Complementing
2                                  Targeted
```

**Third Attempt**

If I reorder the regex list:

```
df['Title'].replace(regex=[r'(\A[\D\s.,]*\d\d\d\da:)', 
                           r'(\A[\D\s.,]*\d\d\d\db:)'
                           r'(\A[\D\s.,]*\d\d\d\d:)'], value='', inplace=True)
```

I get a little improvement, but not enough:

```
                                      Title
0                                    Carbon
1  Bertram, C. et al., 2015b: Complementing
2                                  Targeted
```

**Desired Result**

```
    Title
0   Carbon
1   Complementing
2   Targeted
```

**Lack of Related Questions**

I've closely looked over the documentation for both `re` and `panda`'s `replace`, but something is amiss.  None of the SO Q&A come close to this problem.

Comment: Could you explain what you're trying to remove. And show the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"[ab:]"` means "either a, or b, or :". You need `"[ab:]+"` ("either a, or b, or :, possibly repeated"), because they are repeated in, e.g., `"2015a:"`. With this correction, the first method will work.

Comment: I think what he actually wants is `\d{4}[ab]?:`

Comment: Probably, but in their context, `\d{4}[ab]?:` does not differ from `\d\d\d\d[ab:]+` because : is always at the end.

Comment: But yours will match even if there's no `:` after the year.

Comment: Correct, but in their examples, there is always a ":" after the year.

Comment: Actually both `[ab:]+` and `[ab]?:` worked. Yes, there is always a `:` in every line.

Answer (score 0):

If you always have colon `:` in the end and want to have the last words after it, you may not want to use `re` module. Usually re is much slower than simple string operations.

Alternative could be:

```
data = {'Title' : ['Bertram, C. et al., 2015a: Carbon', 
                   'Bertram, C. et al., 2015b: Complementing', 
                   'Bertram, C. et al., 2018: Targeted']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Title'])
df['title2'] = df.Title.str.split(':').str[-1].str.lstrip()

print(df)
```

output

```
0         Bertram, C. et al., 2015a: Carbon         Carbon
1  Bertram, C. et al., 2015b: Complementing  Complementing
2        Bertram, C. et al., 2018: Targeted       Targeted
```

Comment: Thanks @Bhishan.  That would work nicely in my MWE, but in the actual application there are `:`s before and after the `\d\d\d\d:` where I do not want to split.

Comment: It should work even if you have multiple colons. the part `.str[-1]` will take only the last part after colon `:`. You can give it a try.